# Cannot be applied to given types; actual and formal argument lists differ in length java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement inheritence in java but I keep getting an error:

> HelloWorld.java:27: error: constructor BoxShapes in class
> HelloWorld.BoxShapes cannot be applied to given types;
> Square(int side1){
> ^   required: int,int   found: no arguments

Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
      

     }
     
     
     class BoxShapes{
        int side1, side2;
        
        BoxShapes(int side1, int side2){
            this.side1 = side1;
            this.side2 = side2;
        }
        
        void PrintInfo(){
            System.out.println("The length of side 1 is " + this.side1 + 
            " and the lenght of side2 is " + this.side2);
        }
        
         
     }
     
     class Square extends BoxShapes{
        Square(int side1){
            this.side1 = side1;
        }    
     }
     
     class Rectangle extends BoxShapes{
         Rectangle(int side1, int side2){
             this.side1 = side1;
             this.side2 = side2;
         }
     }
     
     void compuateArea(){
         int area;
         area = this.side1 * this.side2;
         System.out.print("Area of rectanlge is " + area);
     }
     
     void compuatePerimeter(){
         int perimeter;
         perimeter = 2 * (this.side1 + this.side2);
         System.out.println(perimeter);
     }
     
     //@override
     void printInfo(){
        super.printInfo();
     }
}
```

My understanding of the error message is that the the constructor `BoxShapes` expects 2 integers. So I would understand Square class failing but the rectangle class throws the same error as above:

```
>     HelloWorld.java:32: error: constructor BoxShapes in class HelloWorld.BoxShapes cannot be applied to given types;
>              Rectangle(int side1, int side2){
>                                             ^
>       required: int,int
>       found: no arguments
```

So my understanding is not correct.

Comment: The superclass's constructor needs to be invoked as part of instantiating a subclass. If you don't explicitly call a super constructor then implicitly the no-arg super constructor is invoked—but your superclass has no such constructor. To fix that you need to either provide a no-arg constructor in the superclass or invoke the constructor you already have (e.g `Square(int side1) { super(side1, side1); }`).

Comment: @Slaw Understood. That fixed the problem but I am getting an error `error: cannot find symbol
         int area = this.side1 * this.side2;`  It is saying the "." after this is not found.

Comment: Your `computeArea` and `computePerimeter` methods, along with an attempt at overriding `printInfo`, are all currently members of the `HelloWorld` class. Place them in the `BoxShapes` class and/or its subclasses. Also, keep in mind that Java is case-sensitive; `printInfo` is not the same as `PrintInfo` (the former follows standard Java naming conventions by the way, whereas the latter does not).